# synchronize time by remote server

Tags: systemd

How to synchronize time on systemd system (Ubuntu 15.04) using command line?

*(Note: simply running `timedatectl set_ntp true` is not updating the time)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep your system time synchcronised with a remote server, under `systemd`  as of [version 213](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-May/019537.html) (*note: you must be using `systemd-networkd` to manage your network connectivity*) you would use `systemd-timesyncd`. To start and enable this service, run:

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

You can set the time with:

```
timedatectl set-time $current_time
```

See `man timedatectl` for the details.

To configure NTP pool servers to synchromise with, add them in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`, like so:

```
[Time]
NTP=0.arch.pool.ntp.org 1.arch.pool.ntp.org 2.arch.pool.ntp.org 3.arch.pool.ntp.org
FallbackNTP=0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 0.fr.pool.ntp.org
```

As Lennart Poettering notes in the announcement:

> In contrast to NTP
>           implementations such as chrony or the NTP reference server
>           this only implements a client side, and does not bother with
>           the full NTP complexity, focusing only on querying time from
>           one remote server and synchronizing the local clock to
>           it. Unless you intend to serve NTP to networked clients or
>           want to connect to local hardware clocks this simple NTP
>           client should be more than appropriate for most
>           installations.

See the [man page for the service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-timesyncd.service.html) for details.

Comment: i did this, nothing happened. your answer does not shows how to synchronize. but rather turning ON the daemon

Comment: @edward I assumed you would bother to read the man page, where you would have discovered `set-time `...

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
sudo ntpdate 1.in.pool.ntp.org 0.asia.pool.ntp.org 3.asia.pool.ntp.org
```

I got the server address for my region from [pool.ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/)

[source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Date_and_Time_Configuration-Command_Line_Configuration-Network_Time_Protocol.html)

Comment: This doesn't use [tag:systemd]...